# Shared services give promise error in angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am getting error while using shared service in angular 2.

I just added in provider and trying to inject in another component giving me issue.

Could you please help me??
Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code or error as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Only one component can bootstrap throughout the application. You are trying to bootstrap a service. Add the service in the providers. Then it'll work fine.